# How to read values on subscription demand?

Tags: c#, subscription, opc-ua

I am learning OPC-UA with OPC-UA .Net stack. The examples with subscribing and sending data are explicitly made on server side with 1 second cycles of refresh -- i.e. each second the values of the variables are updated, and the rest (notifying clients) is handled by the OPC-UA stack. Since the loop is made by hand it means it will work even there is no subscriptions at all.

Ok. But I would like to reverse it a little -- do not set static value to the variable, do not rely on this manual refresh cycle, but whenever the variable is about to be read (subscription demand), dynamically compute the value and return it to the client.

I added `OnReadValue` handler on the variable and when the client subscribe for that value, it is triggered, the value is computed and returned. Almost exactly what I wished for -- the problem is it is done only **once**.

I guess since client requested updates per some interval, at the server there is some loop going on with such interval. How to tell the server to read the variable again (in order to trigger the handler)?

Comment: Can't you just manually update the value by reading it via its node id? The generic client example implementation should include the code for that.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer, this is about internals of the server (not client). Here how I would like to do it -- client subscribes for some variable with interval 5 seconds. So the server tries to read it each 5 seconds (I guess). In such case I would like to read the value (at the server) from the actual hardware exactly when server tries to refresh the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source of the provided OPC UA-.Net stack I can see now I missed how the data transfer is organized. The reporting interval is not for "give me as many data as possible" but quite the opposite "give me as little data as possible". That is because the server is change-event-driven, not time-driven (or request-driven) -- i.e. any change of the value of variable is noticed and could be happily queued for the reporting, but the interval plays a role of a brake -- if the time of change is smaller than the interval, nothing is added to queue (and thus is not reported).

Client can request continuous reporting though -- interval=0 and some substantial size for the queue.